# Expressing $\frac{1}{4n^2-1}$ as a partial fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

I was asked to express $$\frac{1}{4n^2-1}$$ as a partial fraction. I have no clue as to what I should break this  into. For example I know :

$$\frac{1}{n(n-1)}= \frac {A}{n} + \frac {B}{n-1}$$

These are fractorisable. Whereas $4n-1$ isnt.

**So how to do it when one can't factorize  the denominator?**

Comment: **Hint:**  $4n^2-1=(2n-1)(2n+1).$

Comment: Are you all fighting for upvotes and downvotes? Im sure this question got downvoted because of a fight.

Comment: @Tharindu Clearly you were xNova and another - Based on the bijective mapping of reputation changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{4n^2-1}=\frac{1}{(2n)^2-1}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}=\frac{A}{2n-1}+\frac{B}{2n+1}$$

$A=0.5$, $B=-0.5$

Comment: Thank you very much :D I understood :D

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{4n^2-1}=\frac{1}{(2n)^2-1}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}=\frac{A}{2n-1}+\frac{B}{2n+1}$$

$$1=A(2n+1)+B(2n-1)$$
Set $n=-.5$$$1=A(0)+B(-2)$$
$$B=-\frac12$$
Set $n=.5$
$$1=A(2)+B(0)$$
$$A=\frac12$$

$$=\frac1{4n-2} - \frac1{4n+2}\quad \blacksquare$$

---

If you are doing this for integration:

$$\int \frac{.5}{2n-1} dn-\int\frac{.5}{2n+1} dn$$
$$\frac14\ln|2n-1| - \frac14\ln|2n+1|+C$$
$$\frac14\left(\ln\left|\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\right|\right)+C\quad\blacksquare$$

---

If you are doing limits:

$\lim \limits_{n\to\pm\infty} \frac1{4n^2-1} = 0$

---

If you are doing series:

Comment: Why integration? O.o What is this.

Comment: @XNova Oh sorry, most people do partial fraction decomposition for integration, I just assumed

Comment: Your assumption is wrong :)

Comment: It has been a long time since I was a grade 8 student, when you get to grade 10 this will all be too easy

Comment: Integration is too easy. I wanted this to find the sum to N terms. I know how to do that, how to break this to partial fractions didn't come to my mind...Another assumption is wrong kid, Im not in grade 8

Comment: Oh I don't mean to offend you, partial fractions is normally covered in grade 8 in india, so I assumed that you were in early grade 8, it has been a good 60 years though, so things might have changed!

Comment: I wonder why this is $-3$, it does answer the question, and more(even though unrelated).

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge you should see his first answer. His first answer didn't have the part "If you are integrating" . I downvoted because the question wasn't about integration, or comparing me to a grade 8 student.

Comment: I'm a grade 9 student TT

Comment: @EpicGuy and you could do this /or no?\

Comment: @EpicGuy What is TT? Turn Table?

Comment: @Thursday It's meant to represent a crying face, and I would've found this difficult.

Comment: @EpicGuy You seem intelligent from your answers, keep at it!

Comment: @Thursday Thanks I'm trying the best I can :)